# How to return list of items from linq to sql query and call it in a console application

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, console-application

I am farily new to C# and I am trying to query sql using EF and linq to return a list of items(Policies) from today to a specific date, lets say 60 days ahead, this all happens in a class library,I then want to loop though the items from a console application and list policies of that time period, here is the code I have in the class library.

```
public class Class1
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            using (var context = new CRMContext())
            {
                 context.Policies.Where(p => p.new_RenewalDate == 
                                DateTime.Today.AddDays(60).Date).ToList();

            }
        }
    }
```

I want to call it in the console application

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Class1 instance = new Class1();
        }
    }
```

I want to loop though the items using a for-each loop and write out to console, how can I archive this? Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to assign the policies to a variable, and then loop through it:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    using (var context = new CRMContext())
    {
         var targetDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(60).Date;
         var policies = context.Policies.Where(p => p.new_RenewalDate == targetDate);

         foreach (var policy in policies)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(policy.new_RenewalDate); // etc...
         }
    }
}
```

and in your main program:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Class1 instance = new Class1();
    instance.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Class1 { 
public List<Policy> DoSomething() { 
using (var context = new CRMContext()) 
{
  return context.Policies.Where(p => p.new_RenewalDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(60).Date).ToList();

 }
 }
}




Class1 instance = new Class1();

List<Policy> list = instance.DoSomething();

foreach(Policy policy in list)
{
print what you want to print here :)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return an enumerable from the method you do the work in.

```
public class Class1
{
    // Return list if you need list functionality, otherwise enumerable will do
    public IEnumerable<Policy> DoSomething()
    {
        using (var context = new CRMContext())
        {
             return context.Policies.Where(p => p.new_RenewalDate == 
                            DateTime.Today.AddDays(60).Date).ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 instance = new Class1();
        foreach (var item in instance.DoSomething())
        {
            // Do work on the item here
        }
    }
}
```